# Scala meaning of the following syntax: "c@Req"

Tags: scala

I have a question regarding the following portion of code:

```
sealed trait Claim { val claimId: Int }
case class Full(val claimId: Int) extends Claim
case class Partial(val claimId: Int, percentage: Double) extends Claim
case class Generic(override val claimId: Int) extends Claim

case class Location(stateCode: Option[String], zipCode: Option[String])
case class Req(productId: String, location: Location, claim: Claim)

object PricingSystem {
  type PC = Tuple2[Req, Option[Double]]  

  def handleFullClaim: PartialFunction[PC, PC] = { 
    case (c@Req(id, l, Full(claimId)), basePrice)  =>  (c, basePrice.map(_ + 10))
  }

  def handlePartialClaim: PartialFunction[PC, PC] = { 
    case (c@Req(id, l, Partial(claimId, percentage)), basePrice)  =>  (c, basePrice.map(_ + 20))
  }

  def handleZipCode: PartialFunction[PC, PC] = { 
    case (c@Req(id, Location(_, Some(zipCode)), _), price) => (c, price.map(_ + 5)) 
  }

  def handleStateCode: PartialFunction[PC, PC] = { 
    case (c@Req(id, Location(Some(stateCode), _), _), price) => (c, price.map(_ + 10)) 
  }

  def claimHandlers = handleFullClaim orElse handlePartialClaim
  def locationHandlers = handleZipCode orElse handleStateCode

  def default: PartialFunction[PC, PC] = { case p => p }
  def priceCalculator: PartialFunction[PC, PC] = 
    (claimHandlers andThen locationHandlers) orElse default

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    priceCalculator((Req("some product", Location(None, Some("43230")), Full(1)), Some(10))) match {
      case (c, finalPrice) => println(finalPrice)
    }
    priceCalculator((Req("some product", Location(None, None), Generic(10)), Some(10))) match {
      case (c, finalPrice) => println(finalPrice)
    }
  }

}
```

What does the following snippet mean in scala: **`c@Req`**? Especially: what is the meaning of the **`@`** sign here?

Comment: See this exact question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748858/pattern-matching-symbol/20748908#20748908 "The meaning of @ in pattern matching"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a pattern match `@` binds the variable on the left to the value that is matched on the right. In your code `c` can then be referred to with the value of that pattern that was matched.

See this http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly, "`c`" is an instance of "`case class Req(productId: String, location: Location, claim: Claim)`"? Am I right?

Comment: Not necessarily; `c` matches the pattern `Req(id, l, Full(claimId))`. The `@` symbol allows you to specify both a capture and a pattern which must be matched by the captured value.